# Dynamicly reverse proxy a subfolder to subdomain in Apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I would like to dynamically proxy sub folders to sub domains on another host.  For example, I have the following reverse proxy setup for a single sub folder to sub domain:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /app1/ http://app1.myotherserver.tld/
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://app1.myotherserver.tld/
```

The above works fine (except for the trailing "/" issue).  However, I need to add another 10 just like it, app2, app3, app4, etc... and perhaps more in the future.  It obviously does not make sense to add each one.

Using the page at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html as a reference, I am doing this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ http://$1.myotherserver.tld/ [P]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ http://$1.myotherserver.tld/$2 [P]
ProxyPassReverse /$1/ http://$1.myotherserver.tld/
```

It kind of works, but my existing sub folders get pulled into that rule, and I still have the problem with the trailing "/".

I tried adding a "?" to the first rule, but that breaks everything:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)?/$ http://$1.myotherserver.tld/ [P]
```

How do I make something like "http;//www.mywebserver.tld/app2" work, yet still allow valid URL's such as these to still work?

```
http://www.mywebserver.tld/style.css 
http://www.mywebserver.tld/images/title.png
http://www.mywebserver.tld/existingsubfolder
http://www.mywebserver.tld/existingsubfolder/page.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use rewrite conditions to verify that the files don't exist before proxying.

Also, should be able to get the desired behavior with just one rule:

```
RewriteCond /path/to/docroot%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond /path/to/docroot%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/[^/]*/(.*)$ http://$1.myotherserver.tld/ [P]

ProxyPassReverse /$1/ http://$1.myotherserver.tld/
```

Comment: Sadly I am still struggling with this.  I've been trying to 'learn' how to work with mod_rewrite for several years now.  I thought I could apply a generic example to what I am trying to do specifically at my website.

Comment: I've managed to get it working at http://mining.securepayment.cc/ using this:

RewriteRule ^/pools/(.*)/themes/(.*)/style\.css$ http://$1.securepayment.cc/themes/$2/style.css [P]
RewriteRule ^/pools/(.*)/themes/(.*)/(.*)\.png$ http://$1.securepayment.cc/themes/$2/$3.png [P]
RewriteRule ^/pools/(.*)/([^/]*)$ http://$1.securepayment.cc/$2 [P]
ProxyPassReverse /pools/$1/ http://$1.securepayment.cc/

Is there any way to avoid having to provide specific rules for images and style sheets under a sub folder?